# How do make regular backups of a shared Google folder?

Tags: google-drive, backup

I hope this is the good community to ask this question. 
I am sharing a Google Drive folder as a work folder for a number of people. They need to have the ability to edit, but I also need to assure that no data loss happens as a result of mistake or malintent.

I was hoping to create another Google Drive folder that would backup regularly and this locked for my use only. However, I can't find how to reach this goal.

Comment: Google has revision history. Every change is backed up. Just roll back to an older version.

Comment: Rolling back to an older version seems to be applicable for files but not for whole folders?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to sync the Google Drive folder to a local machine. Add that folder to a shared folder for a different cloud service (e.g. Dropbox), and the changes will also be synced to that other service, which presumably has its own revision history as well.

Comment: I tried this option with OneDrive, but couldn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a basic programming skill (or advanced then better) you may use Google APIs which is still for free hopefully. Python, Ruby, Java or whatever...
You may also can use sync folder on a Linux machine, and create a Tarbar of your desired Folder everyday using cron, or on Windows but I have no clue about it.

Comment: It might be easier to use Google Apps Script than using the Google Drive API and the Editors APIs.